# include files from anywhere on the server

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I have website running perfectly on production server. I have moved it to another web server. (VPS).

Let me explain you with example:
The directory structure:

```
includes/
        header.php
business/
        index.php
        some other files...
index2.php
```

In my previous version, I used

```
include_once(includes/header.php)
```

in index.php and index2.php. It runs fine. but in my new server setup it's giving me error regarding path (obvious).

ERROR:

```
include_once(includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

And because of that:

```
Fatal error: Class 'EncryptionClass' not found
```

I think there are some server configurations which I need to do. But, I don't know how?
Please guide me. Let me know if you want more information.

Comment: And what error would that be? The message is likely important, especially if it mentions open_basedir. For starters, `business/index.php` should be including `../includes/header.php`, not `includes/header.php`...

Comment: It's likely a permissions issue if the directory structure has not changed at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz: ya.. That's the correct path. but in my old server setup. my entire site works fine. And this is not only 1 file. I need to change lots of things because of this.

Answer (score 3):

if using PHP 5.3+ Try using:

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/includes/header.php');
```

[**DIR**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is a magic constant that will return the full directory that the file is in.

Comment: I know. but I don't want to go each and every file which I wrote.

Comment: Use something like Sublime Text -> Find in Files, to perform a global find and replace.

Comment: Pre 5.3 can use `dirname(__FILE__)` in place of `__DIR__` (not that anybody should be using 5.2 or lower any more)

Answer (score 2):

You could supply an absolute file system path to the include:

`include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/header.php");`

Comment: that's perfect solution. But, that would be massive change. i need to change lots of files.

Comment: Do you know any kind of server configuration by means of which we can handle this silly thing.

Comment: Personally I would do a global search across all files in the project to update all includes/requires with this or Michael P's answer. You could muck around with the php functions get_include_path(), set_include_path(), and restore_include_path(), but I think that would be even messier.

Comment: And what if the server doesn't populate the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` environment variable or even more common, the script is run outside of a web / application server context (ie CLI)?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add your `includes` directory to the `include_path`. For example, in `index2.php`

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__ . '/includes', // relative to this file, index2.php
    get_include_path()
]));

include_once 'header.php';
```

and similarly in `business/index.php`...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__ . '/../includes', // relative to this file, business/index.php
    get_include_path()
]));

include_once 'header.php';
```

Personally, I would use [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) file-to-class name mappings and configure an autoloader, eg

#### includes/EncryptionClass.php

```
class EncryptionClass { ... }
```

#### index2.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/' . $class . '.php';
});

$encryptionClass = new EncryptionClass();
```