# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does not include PHP project Name

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am currently facing the Issue with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] function on local server. as it does not include the Project Name in the Path. I used

```
define('DOC_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

and include the file like.

```
require(DOC_ROOT.'/includes/libs/SmartyBC.class.php');
```

But it giving me the warning like in error_log.

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:/wamp64/www/includes/libs/SmartyBC.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\bluepearl\config\configuration.php on line 36
```

Path should be like.

```
require(C:/wamp64/www/bluepearl/includes/libs/SmartyBC.class.php)
```

as DOC_ROOT does not include project name in the path, If I Put static path like

```
define('DOC_ROOT','C:/wamp64/www/bluepearl'); - it works
```

I also used 'dirname(*FILE*)' to get the current directory but it append backward slash instead of forward slash.

```
ex. c:\wamp64\www\pearl/includes/libs/SmartyBC.class.php.
```

Please Guide Me. Thank you.

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set by your HTTP server (Apache, nginx, IIE, etc). I would advise not relying on it at all. Instead, configure PHP's `include_path` relative to your main entry-point `.php` script. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21472244/283366

Comment: PHP handles windows backward-slash directory separators just fine. You don't need to worry about it

Comment: Yup, I read about that Php handles backward-slash, but still Can't figure it out why I am getting that error 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory'.

Comment: @Phil : My question is not how to include file from anywhere on the server, I am asking why project name does not include in the path when I used DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Because your HTTP server sets the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to `C:/wamp64/www`. The other question has answers which show how to use `__DIR__` to include files relative to the current `.php` script